# How to unstack unique column values to columns and set another column as row index in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pandas-groupby

I have a table as given below.

[image]

I am trying to rearrange the table in a certain manner so that I have the unique values of the column 'Metric Category' as separate columns and the corresponding values from the 'Response' column as values. Though I have been able to solve till here with the following code

```
df2.set_index([df2.groupby(['Metric_Category'])['Metric_Category'].cumcount(), 'Metric_Category'])['Response'].unstack()
```

[image]

However, I am unable to figure out how to add the corresponding 'Participant' name alongside the responses as follows.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add column `Participant` to `MultiIndex`:

```
df2.set_index(['Participant',df2.groupby(['Metric_Category'])['Metric_Category'].cumcount(), 'Metric_Category'])['Response'].unstack()
```